# ASP.Net Core - Applying updates to an already published Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I published my first ASP.Net Core project as an Azure Web App using Visual Studio 2015. It has a SQL database component.

I then modified the web app locally and tried to publish again and was given an error about a database not being able to be created. It seems that publishing changes with the same settings was attempting to recreate the existing database.

I followed the publishing instructions from the official docs here:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vs.html

The above instructions don't include what to do when one wants to push an update to an already published web app. However I was successfully able to publish an update by going into settings in the publish window and unchecking "Apply Migration on Publish".

What do I need to do if I make changes to the database structure itself (tables/columns/etc). How can I successfully publish this? The documentation seems sparse regarding this.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an ASP.NET Core related issue. I assume that you use the code first approach and then you want to modify the database. In order to to this, you need to do a migration (or if possible, delete the content of the database prior to publishing the changes - not an option if you have data). [Maybe have a look at this article?](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/new-db.html) Best of luck!

Comment: I understand applying migrations to the local version of the database. What I don't understand is doing the same for the "live" version of the database hosted on Azure. Thanks for the link, I'll check it out